# How to mock datetime with java.time.clock?

Tags: java, scala, datetime, java-time

Why the date generated with below code offset the given time to 11:00:00.00?

```
test("shouldReturnGivenMockedDateTime") {
  val mockedDateTime = "2020-01-01T10:00:00.00Z"
  val clock: Clock = Clock.fixed(Instant.parse(mockedDateTime), TimeZone.getDefault.toZoneId);
  val result = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(clock.instant, TimeZone.getDefault.toZoneId)
  assert(result.toString == "2020-01-01T10:00") // FALSE!!!
  assert(result.toString == "2020-01-01T11:00") // TRUE
}
```

Comment: Could you check, what `TimeZone.getDefault` returns? Is it possible that your default timezone is GMT+1?

Comment: its `Europe/Belgrade` it should be UTC+2 now https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/serbia/belgrade

Comment: Instead of `TimeZone.getDefault.toZoneId` just use `ZoneId.systemDefault`. The `TimeZone` class too is poorly designed and long outdated, so I have made it a habit not to use it.

Comment: result is the same

Answer (score 5):

> Why the date generated with below code offset the given time to
>   11:00:00.00?

Your mock date is 1st January, 2020. According to your link, Belgrade was at offset     UTC+1h on this date. From 27th October 2019 until 29th March 2020, more precisely. The mocked date and time is also in UTC, denoted by the trailing `Z`. When querying the time in your local time zone, Europe/Belgrade, 1 hour is added to the UTC time, so 10:00 becomes 11:00.

You are correct, of course, that Belgrade is at offset +02:00 here in May (because of summer time/DST). Only when converting a date and time in January, the offset that was valid back then is used, not the offset for May.

Repeating your link: [2020 Time Zones - Belgrade](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/serbia/belgrade)